# Need help reading from a file in C

Tags: c, arrays, file-io

I have been looking around for a solution but cannot seem to find a solution to my question so I will ask it. I am working in C and am reading in a .txt and taking all the values and storing them in an array then doing various tasks with them. Now my problem is that no matter what I do I cannot get file pointer I create to point to the file for some reason. I have done this for projects in the past and have compared my code then to the current one and cannot see the issue. The filename needs to be read in from the command line as well. I think there is something wrong with what I'm passing through the command line but am not sure. I have stepped through and the filename is being passed correctly but when it tries to open I get a null pointer so there is just something I'm missing.

The text file will contain a series of numbers, the first number will be the number of numbers in the file after that first number. (So if the number is 10 then there will be ten numbers after 10 is read in) after that first number the remaining numbers will be 0-9 in a random order.

Below is my current chunk of code only involving reading of the file and storing its data. (I already know the array will be of size 10 which is why the array is declared with that size.)

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 char* filename = "numbers.txt";
 int arr[10];
 int numElem;
 int indexDesired = 0;

FILE *fp;
fp = fopen(filename, "r"); // open file begin reading
if (!fp) 
{
    printf("The required file parameter name is missing\n");
    system("pause");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
else
{
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &numElem); //scans for the first value which will tell the number of values to be stored in the array

    int i = 0;
    int num;
    while (i <= numElem) //scans through and gets the all the values and stores them in the array.
    {
        fscanf(fp, "%d", &num);
        arr[i] = num;
        i++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
 }
}
```

***note: My sort and swap method work perfectly so I have omitted them from the code as the error happens before they are even called.

Comment: Also I am working on Visual studios 2013.

Comment: So you're getting output _"The required file parameter name is missing"_ ?

Comment: In your code the filename is not received from the command line. Also what is the output you see?

Comment: can you use the full path of the file instead of just the name

Comment: I get the output "The required file parameter name is missing" as you say. I have tried using the full path and pasting it into the command line and even step through to ensure that it is the correct spot in argv[]

Comment: just in the name use the full path and test it. Also make sure the permission of the file is also correct.Also before pasue use perror http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/perror/ to print the exact error

Comment: I have tried using the full path and get the same error. How do I check the permission of the file? Also I read your link but will perror display it automatically or must I type the error message?

Comment: just add perror ("file opening error "); before pause

Answer (score 2):

you said,

> The filename needs to be read in from the command line as well.

However, you are using:

```
char* filename = "numbers.txt";
```

and

```
fp = fopen(filename, "r"); // open file begin reading
```

No matter what you are passing in the command line, the file you are trying to open is `"numbers.txt"`.

Things to try:

1. Use the full path name of `"numbers.txt"` instead of just the name of the file.

   ```
   char* filename = "C:\\My\\Full\\Path\\numbers.txt";
   ```

   If that doesn't work, you will probably have to deal with permissions issues.
2. Pass the file name  from the command line, using the full path. That should work if there are no permissions issues.

   ```
   if ( argc < 2 )
   {
       // Deal with unspecified file name.
   }
   char* filename = argv[1];
   ```
3. Pass the relative path of the file name. If you are testing your program from Visual Studio, you have to make sure that you use the path relative to the directory from where Visual Studio launches your program.

Comment: Also you may find using `perror("The required file parameter name is missing\n");` rather than `printf("The required file parameter name is missing\n");` to he helpful as it will print the reason the open failed (file not found, permission denied, etc)

Comment: THANKS! I knew I was doing something stupid and it was that when using the path I was forgetting to add an extra \ to it so my path was: C:\My\Full\Path\numbers.txt as opposed to the two \s like you have. I knew I needed them somewhere just from encountering this issue when I did past projects I just forgot where thank you again! I do need it to read the command line but wanted it to work through just setting the filename first and it now works for both so thank again! :-)

Comment: @bobHarding, you are welcome. Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
  while (i <= numElem)
```

should be

```
   while (i < numElem)
```

Because in `fscanf(fp, "%d", &numElem);` you are scanning the number of elements.

Notice that the array in C starts from 0, so if say `numElem` is `10` `arr[10]` does not exist which can be harmful because arr goes from `arr[0]` to `arr[9]`

Also, you should check if `numElem` is  lower than 10 before the `while(i < numElem)` loop.

Comment: Normally I would but my professor is not requiring error handling. Thanks for correcting that though I would have probably caught it once I made it passed this error. Thanks again though!

Comment: Could put `int arr[10];` after the `fscanf(fp, "%d", &numElem);` as `int arr[numElem];`.  But then one would need an up-to-date C compiler.